# Set all dictionary keys to 1 causes crash BAD_ACCESS Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is saved as an `NSUserDefault` declared globally:

```
var fruitDictionary = NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("fruits") as [String:Int]
```

This dictionary contains fruit names and then a value which is either 0 or 1. I am trying to set all values to 1 (most of them are currently set to 0) using the following method:

```
func setFruit() {

    //Set all dictionary items to have the value 1
    for key in fruitDictionary.keys{
        fruitDictionary[key] = 1 //Crashes here: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code=1
    }

    defaults.setObject(fruitDictionary, forKey: "fruits") //Save fruit dictionary
}
```

Any ideas on what might be the cause of this or how I should debug it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

edit/update: In Swift 4 or later you can use Dictionary mapValues method to change all your dictionary values to 1 as follow:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["apple": 0, "banana" : 1], forKey: "fruits")
```

---

```
var fruitDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "fruits") as? [String:Int] ?? [:]
```

---

```
func setFruit() {
    //Set all dictionary items to have the value 1
    fruitDictionary = fruitDictionary.mapValues({ _ in 1 })
    UserDefaults.standard.set(fruitDictionary, forKey: "fruits") //Save fruit dictionary
}
```

---

```
setFruit()

fruitDictionary["apple"] // 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So rather than setting the values inside the for loop, I should set them manually like `["apple":5, "orange": 6, "banana": 9]`?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. I am already familiar with setting user defaults. I have already been using them to save all the high scores and user settings for the game.

Comment: This answer does not actually explain why the code crashes. How about instead of just throwing alternative code in an answer, actually explain why the original code is not doing what is expected?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus I think you should explain it to the OP because I very much doubt that he understand what was going on in his own code. You only gave alternative code, which does something very different than what he asked for, without any explanation. This is a low quality answer that does not help the larger community.